# How do I use a math symbol from the private use area with unicode-math?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, unicode-math

There are many math symbols which are not, unfortunately, in Unicode. One such symbol is the sequent relational operator that looks something like this ">-" and is found in the literature. I have a custom font, where this symbol is in the private use area. Using both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, I can load the font and display it in text mode. The symbol is only defined in a normal weight, non-italic form. However, I cannot successfully define it as a math operator. This is the result of compiling the file...

[image: Result of compiling file]

Here is a minimal, commented `.tex` file that compiles to .pdf with both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, but gives the wrong result for the math operator.

```
% Build .pdf using lualatex or xelatex

\documentclass{amsart}

% Load fontspec, unicode-math.

   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \usepackage{unicode-math}

% Load MyFont font

   \newfontface \MyFont {MyFont.ttf}

% Define Sequent operator in math mode.

   \DeclareSymbolFont{MyFont}{U}{cmr}{m}{n}

   \DeclareMathSymbol{\mathSequent}{\mathrel}{MyFont}{"E8A8}               

% Define Sequent operator in text mode.

   \newcommand \textSequent {{\MyFont{\char"E8A8}}}                        

\begin{document}
   \begin{flushleft}

      This is what the sequent operator looks like in text mode: \textSequent.\\
      This is what the sequent operator looks like in math mode: $\mathSequent$.

      \end{flushleft}
   \end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you find a solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417871/105976

Comment: Regretfully, no. That was actually my question some time ago (I have been very busy and am just getting back to this), and that answer is already incorporated into this question. It is why the symbol works in text mode. I can always wrap the symbol in text mode when in math mode - but that doesn't allow TeX to do its proper spacing for operators.

Comment: just because a symbol isn't in unicode doesn't mean it can't be added.  what is required is documentation: one or more examples in published form, preferably from a "known" publisher.  the examples should show usage, preferably with a definition, along with the citation so that the reference can be located by the committee.  for a few more months, i will be in a position to submit new items to unicode with a good chance they will be accepted.  (i conveyed the stix submission to the unicode technical committee, most of which were added in unicode 4.0, and i still have the connection.)

Comment: The first use of it that I am aware of is in "Stephen Blamey. [1986] "Partial Logic." Handbook of Philosophical Logic, Volume III, Ed. Dov M. Gabbay and F. Guenthner, Kluwer Academic Publishers, 1986, ISBN 0-7923-3098-6." It is was probably as mashup of ">" and "-" then. Since then it looks more like mine. I can provide a font with just that symbol. There are other papers using the symbol, but I can't find them quickly.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is first used and defined on pages 58-59.

Comment: You're declared `MyFont` as Computer Modern Roman. So you'll get whatever CMR has there, which is apparently an 'h'.

Comment: What should I use instead? I tried "U" but that gave the same result in LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX didn't like it. These symbols are entirely contained in the private use area and are NOT in Unicode (although a few duplicate symbols in Unicode). It seems to me that E8A8 (I also tried putting in the decimal equivalent) is picking up what is at 68. If I use E8A9 it picks up an "i" instead of a "h". Computer Modern Roman shouldn't have anything in the private use area. I tried different variations, including DeclareFontFamily and DeclareFontShape which either didn't work at all or got the same result.

Comment: In standard LaTeX you have the symbol ``\succ``, that  has more or less the same look as the one you are looking for, and perhaps  the same meaning .

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out, but this is only a test symbol. I have hundreds, so I still need to solve the problem. Update: Not even close to the same symbol.

Comment: Is this by any chance the same as ⊱ (U+22B1 Succeeds under relation) or ≻  (U+227B Succeeds)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I almost had it right. Instead of "cmr", it was necessary to declare the family and then use it. Instead of U, TU was required. `\DeclareMathSymbol` works if a) the declared family was used and b) the character was FF or less. Because of the latter problem with `\DeclareMathSymbol` it was necessary to instead use `\Umathchardef`. The modified code is shown below, with the replaced lines commented out. There is an extra commented out line for `\DeclareMathSymbol` showing how it should be used for those cases where it works.

The updated version has been tested with both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX. Where I have used MyFontB and MyFontC I wanted to make it clear where the same value has to be used. MyFontB represents an arbitrary font family name. MyFontC represents an arbitrary symbol font name. Notice that the fontface name is never used, except when defining the symbol in text mode. The family name can be the same as the fontface name, but still has to be defined.

I also found that the type of math symbol (mathbin, mathrel, etc.) doesn't make any practical difference, unless I remove the sidebearings (white space to the left and right of the glyph, used for minimum spacing in text) in the font itself. Then, the type of math symbol works as expected. Apparently when the font is loaded, the sidebearings are not stripped out. That would be ok if those symbols are never directly used in text. Since they could be wrapped in math mode, that shouldn't be a problem. I can create a custom variant of the font with zero width sidebearings. There may be some arcane way to have TeX remove the sidebearings, but I haven't found it.

```
% Build .pdf using lualatex or xelatex

\documentclass{amsart}

% Load fontspec, unicode-math.

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

% Load MyFont font

%  \newfontface \MyFont {MyFont.ttf}

\newfontface \MyFont {MyFont.ttf}[NFSSFamily=MyFontB]

% Define Sequent operator in math mode.

%  \DeclareSymbolFont{MyFont}{U}{cmr}{m}{n}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MyFontC}{TU}{MyFontB}{m}{n}

%  \DeclareMathSymbol{\mathSequent}{\mathrel}{MyFont}{"E8A8}               
%  \DeclareMathSymbol{\mathSequent}{\mathrel}{MyFontC}{"E8A8}               
\Umathchardef\mathSequent="3 \symMyFontC "E8A8

% Define Sequent operator in text mode.

\newcommand \textSequent {{\MyFont{\char"E8A8}}}                        

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
   This is what the sequent operator looks like in text mode: \textSequent.\\
      This is what the sequent operator looks like in math mode: $\mathSequent$.
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer is correct. I made a feature request https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/485

Answer (score 0):

In `unicode-math` 0.81, `\setmathfont[range="E8A8]` unfortunately fails when the requested character is in the Private Use Area.  Here is a workaround.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

% \setmainfont goes here.
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
% \setsansfont, \setmonofont, etc. go here.

\newfontface\mathsymbolfont{MyFont.ttf}
\DeclareRobustCommand\textsequent{{\mathsymbolfont\symbol{"E8A8}}\relax}
\DeclareRobustCommand\sequent{\mathrel{\text{\textsequent}}}

\begin{document}
In text mode, the sequent symbol is \textsequent.

In math mode, \(A \sequent B\).

Compare \(A \succ B\).
\end{document}
```

[image: From custom TTF font]

The symbol is, according to the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbols List, also in two packages on CTAN, of which `stmaryrd` got an update early this century and is still usable:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amssymb} % Used by stmaryrd
\usepackage{stmaryrd} % For \Yright
\usepackage{unicode-math} % Or font packages of choice.
\DeclareRobustCommand\sequent{\mathrel{\Yright}}

\begin{document}
In math mode, \(A \sequent B\).

Contrast \(A \succ B\).
\end{document}
```

[image: Example using stmaryrd]

#### ETA:

There is a similar symbol in Unicode, available in `unicode-math` as `\righttail`, although you might need to load it from another font.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{stmaryrd} % \Yright
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchUppercase, range={\righttail}]{STIX Two Math}

\newcommand\sequent{\mathrel\righttail}

\begin{document}
Compare \(A \sequent B\) to \(A \mathrel\Yright B\).
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample of \righttail]

Comment: This works for 7E, but not for E8A8 - apparently it also has the 8-bit limitation. Also, the Succeeds and Succeeds Under Relation have an entirely different purpose and is not an acceptable substitute. They also would just look wrong for someone expecting a sequent symbol.

Comment: There's no 8-bit limitation in unicode-math. I don't have a copy of the font to test it, though. You're putting the actual name of your font inside the braces? What are you getting?

Comment: I used the following commands
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}[slash-delimiter=frac]
\setmathfont[range="E8A8]{MyFont.ttf}
\DeclareRobustCommand \sequent {\mathrel{\char"E8A8}}
It gave me nothing at all. I replaced E8A8 with 7E and it worked.

Comment: I switched from MyFont.ttf to Calibri. It worked for 221B, but not for anything I tried above 7FFF. Those were not math symbols, so I will look for another font with math symbols above 7FFF.

Comment: I tried Arial Unicode MS and it did not work for 7FBD - so it might be that "range=" only works for existing ranges.

Comment: I moved that to the \usepackage command, but it didn't make a difference. Page 6 of the 0.81 manual says "Package options may also be used when declaring new maths fonts, passed via options to the \setmathfont command". Since that option is specific to Cambria Math, it made sense to pass the option there. Also, if you use an unrecognized option it will not compile.

Comment: @MichaelLeeFinney Page 19 of the v0.81 manual says, "When using Cambria Math, then unicode-math should be loaded with the `slash-delimiter=frac` option. (This should be a font option rather than a package option, but it will change soon.)" However, that does not seem to be your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80000/discussion-between-michael-lee-finney-and-davislor).

Comment: @MichaelLeeFinney I've submitted a new answer. Thank you for the file.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to see which approach works better or is more convenient. As far as the \succ symbol, it is part of a set of comparison operators and could be used at the same time as the \sequent relation. They may appear to be superficially the same - but their intended uses are entirely different. Appearance is not the only criteria in selecting a symbol. In a symbol list for older LaTeX, I found some fonts provide \Yright which is not available in Unicode that I can find and does look the same. I don't know if it is a relational operator or defined for some other purpose.

Comment: Right. Maybe I should have said, "Contrast A ≻ B." @barbarabeeton often asks if there are any mathematical symbols in use that need to be added to Unicode, so I hope she sees this.

Comment: She already has, and I gave a reference of the symbol in the literature and I can provide a sample font with the symbol. There are more references, but I don't have time to track them down with no way to find them other than rereading hundreds of papers. I am not too concerned, because by the time I get everything published I expect to have nearly a hundred new symbols for Unicode (which is seriously deficit in arrows) - not to mention that I need a slab serif mathematical font. Using Rockwell Nova (or Rockwell) right now.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `\Yright`. Added an example using `stmaryrd`.

Comment: @MichaelLeeFinney And found a closer match, perhaps close enough, perhaps not.

Comment: Thanks. Not really close enough. However, in case my font is not available, I have settled on STIX2 as my main and math fonts. From there I have built almost all of my important symbols using LaTeX which gives nearly identical results. I am matching glyph shape, size, position and sidebearings with only minor variations. Most of that will also work with Cambria as well - probably all with tweaks. I have noted that many STIX glyphs give me a divide by 0 when I use \xxx, but if I use {Umathchar "0 \symMathFont "HHHH} it does not. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

While not directly an answer in terms of using the font (which was previously answered, in two different ways). For this specific symbol, I have found two ways to create it directly in LaTex. The first is *almost* indistinguishable from the original (with slight differences depending on the math font). The second is fairly close, but is clearly different. Both would be close enough to use in practice, with the first being preferable.

This uses the scalerel package.

```
{\vstretch{0.90}{\hstretch{0.50}{{\mkern5mu}{>}{\mkern-3mu}{-}{\mkern5mu}}}}
```

This uses the graphicx package.

```
{\mkern3mu{\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{\raisebox{-1pt}{\Yup}}}\mkern3mu}
```