# How to get \backprime if the main math font is Cambria Math?

Tags: math-mode, xetex, luatex, unicode-math, tex-gyre-math

Running `xelatex` on

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{CambriaMath.ttf}
%\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX,range={\backprime}]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
%\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX,range={"2035}]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
%\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX,range={"02035}]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
%\setmathfont[range={\backprime}]{texgyretermes-math.otf}
%\setmathfont[range={"2035}]{texgyretermes-math.otf}
%\setmathfont[range={"02035}]{texgyretermes-math.otf}
\begin{document}
\(\sigma^{\backprime}\)
\end{document}
```

with both CambriaMath.ttf and texgyretermes-math.otf in the working directory results in

[image: bogus output]

As the reader sees above, I undertook several attempts of using `\setmathfont`; none of them works for me. `lualatex` produces a no better result.

How to get the reverse prime (as the right superscript) when using Cambria Math as the main math font?  Of course, I'd also like to get proper copyable Unicode `σ‵` (or similar for the backprime) in the text layer of PDF produced.

Versions used:

- This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex 2019.4.18)
- LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
- Document Class: standalone 2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
- Package: unicode-math 2019/02/15 v0.8n Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
- Cambria Math versions 5.96 or 6.96 (the only difference wrt. issue is that the missing-symbol image looks differently).

Crosspost: http://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/529

Comment: I have compiled your code with Papeeria and I have the correct output: https://www.papeeria.com/p/704897e5-7ef7-4eba-a4a6-60b518cb05f8#/main.tex. Try to put your code into main.tex (delete it); you choice with menu (downarrow) TexLive2019 and after click on Compile.

Comment: You're right. Honestly I don't know :-( sigma is different looks like the classic CM. In the background there is your code.

Comment: Are you sure that you want `CambriaMath.ttf` and not `cambria_01.ttf` or `cambria.ttc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One side note: on many systems, Cambria Math will be in the file `cambria_01.ttf` or `cambria.ttc`.  Therefore, the only portable way to select it is by its display name.  That’s not the cause of your error, but it’s something I needed to change to get your MWE to compile.

It’s a bug in `unicode-math` that `range=\backtick` and `range="2035` don’t work.  As of August 2019, `\DeclareMathSymbol` does not work either.  Here is a workaround, based on [this answer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439983/61644)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}

\setmathfont{Cambria Math}

\newfontface\STIXTwoMath{STIX Two Math}[NFSSFamily=STIXTwoFamily]
\DeclareSymbolFont{Missing}{TU}{STIXTwoFamily}{m}{n}
\Umathchardef\varbackprime="0 \symMissing "2035

\newcommand\textbackprime{{\STIXTwoMath\symbol{"2035}}}

\begin{document}
\(\sigma^{\varbackprime}\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Cambria & STIX Two sample]

This has more space to the sides of the tick than you might want.

A simpler approach is to use `\text` from `amsmath` to display the symbol from text mode. à la `\textbackprime` above.

Comment: @MdAyq6 This one is closely related: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/485

Comment: @MdAyq6 TrueType collections are supported [through fontspec.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf#22)

Comment: Always very good :-) is the first time I read the extension .ttc. What files are they?

Comment: @MdAyq6 The way that just works is the way I wrote it: `\setmathfont{Cambria Math}`. If you want to make sure you’re loading the right version, `\setmathfont{cambria.ttc}[FontIndex=1]`. You need to know, or at least guess, the index of the font you want within the `.ttc`. You don’t have to load `fontspec` separately: `unicode-math` loads it and supports all its commands. To see if it worked, run `pdffonts` on the output file or check the log to see if the font has `script=MATH`.

Comment: @Davislor Very near to the 10k :-) My sincere compliments.