How to define a math symbol from a custom font e.g. integral, respecting displaystyle
Basically i defined a few custom glyphs i really want to be able to use by making a font. They are symbols that should be typset exactly the way the integral is typeset in computer modern (but look like i want).
I use Lualatex so that my font doesnt have to be installed on the system to use, i want to simply put a my .ttf into my tex project.
I downloaded  the computer modern fonts from here and modified the integral symbols. As far as i understand it has different files for different math styles:

cmsy10.ttf for standard smaller math symbols such as $\textstyle\int$ (U+0073)?
cmex10.ttf for large math symbols such as $\displaystyle\int$ (U+005a) but also (U+0052) which looks to me like $\textstyle\int$.Why both?

Difficulties:

How to actually include the font and provide commands like \myintegral for my integral symbol? I dont want to use my font for anything else than providing these commands. It should behave exactly like the usual integral and therefore respect if we are in displaystyle or not. I looked for inspiration at fontmath.ltx where

\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{"52}
\DeclareRobustCommand\int{\intop\nolimits}

this definition somehow seems to respect math style (how?).

The bounding boxes of the downloaded files seem wrong no? This is the unchanged displaystyle integral from cmex10.ttf opened in fontforge. All the boxes in cmex.ttf are like this, the ones in cmsy10.ttf are like expected. (The display integral goes alot over the boundary on the right and all the symbols seem to have incorrect baseline?)



Do i have to make a separate symbol for every document text size like the computer modern seems to do?


EDIT:
I have gotten as far as getting my symbols to show and be usable in math mode. However i have problems with the boundary boxes and with the limits even in the cases where i use the standard definition!

The generating code is:
% !TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[ngerman,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
%\usepackage{newcomputermodern}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439983/294323
\newfontface{\mysymbolsfontface}{cmex10_mod.ttf}[
    Path = ./,          % Adjust the path to where the font is located
    Extension = .ttf,
    NFSSFamily=mysymbolsfontfamily %use some name for the font family
]
\DeclareSymbolFont{mysymbolsfont}{TU}{mysymbolsfontfamily}{m}{n}
\Umathchardef\displaymyint="1 \symmysymbolsfont "005A %"\sym" then symbolsfontname then glyph code. The "1 stands for mathoperator 
\DeclareRobustCommand\myint{\mathchoice{\displaymyint\nolimits}
{\intop\nolimits}
{\intop\nolimits}
{\intop\nolimits}}



\begin{document}

Inline: \qquad\qquad\qquad \fbox{$\myint$} \quad \fbox{$\myint_\infty^\infty f(x)$}\\
Displaymode: \qquad\qquad\qquad \fbox{$\displaystyle\myint$} \quad \fbox{$\displaystyle\myint_\infty^\infty f(x)$}\\

Original Inline: \quad \fbox{$\int$} \quad \fbox{$\int_\infty^\infty f(x)$}\\
Original Displaymode: \quad \fbox{$\displaystyle\int$} \quad \fbox{$\displaystyle\int_\infty^\infty f(x)$}\\
\end{document}

So what remains to be answered is:

Why arent the limits right in the case where \intop is used? Should be like in original tex no?
Where can i get a version of the cmex font, where the boxes are correct?


EDIT: I decided to split this last part into a more accessible question, see here. This is basically closed.
